# trying to stop horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a div and set its initial position

```
<div class="guide" >
<style>
  .guide{
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-170px;
    top: 10%;
  }
</style>
```

What i want when i click on the div it should comeout from right side.
The problem is window is providing hrizontal scroll, so if a person scrolls to right the div is compltely visible.
I want to stop horizontal scroll so that if the user click on div then only its visible.
Now if any body explain that why its going after -ve pixels, becouse sometime it doesn't go beyond   -ve px, sometime it goes, why?

Comment: give parent container overflow:hidden.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umubw1af/ is it what you want?

Comment: plz explain y its going beyond -ve pixels. @Mr_Green

Comment: @PJ1405 it will not scroll beyond negative pixels if you give overflow:hidden to that container.

Answer (score 7):

Add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the Parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal Scrollbar :
`overflow-x: hidden;`

Vertical Scrollbar : 
`overflow-y: hidden;`

both: `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

Hide vertical scrollbar of a parent div by using

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: How your answer is different from other already present answers?